# C# filter objects with BindingSource in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, filter, bindingsource

I am having a problem with filtering my data in a `BindingSource`. I am listing the data in a `DataGridView`.

```
class client
{

    public int id { get; set; }
    public String name { get; set; }


    public client(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = 0;
    }
}    

BindingSource clients = new BindingSource();

clients.Add(new client("Test1"));
clients.Add(new client("Test2"));

dataGridView_clients.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
dataGridView_clients.ColumnCount = 2;

dataGridView_clients.Columns[0].Name = "id";
dataGridView_clients.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "id";

dataGridView_clients.Columns[1].Name = "name";
dataGridView_clients.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "name";

dataGridView_clients.DataSource = clients_source;

clients.Filter = string.Format("Name = 'Test1'");
dataGridView_clients.Refresh();
```

What am I doing wrong? The filter doesn't work, it is being shown in the last two clients.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "it is being shown in the last two clients". What is being shown? What are you expecting?

Comment: I have the clients "Test1" and "Test2" in my BindingSource. Now I want wo filter the name Test1, but nothing happens. Also also tried it with a BindingList

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because `BindingSource`, by default, does not support filtering. If you debug your code, you will see that the property `SupportsFiltering` is `false`.

[image]

To solve this, you need to implement a `IBindingListView`, and bind then to your `BindingSource`, because you can implement how the filter will work.

You can follow the steps described in this article to implement the `IBindingListView`.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winformsue/2007/12/07/implementing-the-ibindinglistview-for-filtering/

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your binding source handle filtering like this

```
clients.SupportsFiltering.ToString()
```

In your case, filtering is not supported.
To solve this, you can implement IBindingListView interface on it.
See : [Implementing the IBindingListView for filtering](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winformsue/2007/12/07/implementing-the-ibindinglistview-for-filtering/)

Answer (score 0):

You can filter a list before data binding:

```
List<client> clients = new List<client> { new client("Test1"), new client("Test2") };

List<client> filtered = clients.FindAll(c => c.name == "Test2");

dataGridView1.DataSource = filtered;
```